# Looping with smarty?

Tags: php, loops, twitter-bootstrap, smarty

I am using smarty and bootstrap,

I am building an image gallery so my markup ends up being as posted below.

I know I can loop over my categories as `{foreach $categories as $category}{/foreach}`
But as you can see by the markup posted below I need to wrap the in groups of four.
That's the part I don't know how to do.

Also, note that there may not always be a multiple of four, e.g. there could be 15 categories.

How should I do this?

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt=""></a>

                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>

                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida
                        at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt=""></a>

                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>

                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida
                        at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt=""></a>

                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>

                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida
                        at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt=""></a>

                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>

                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida
                        at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt=""></a>

                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>

                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida
                        at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt=""></a>

                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>

                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida
                        at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt=""></a>

                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>

                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida
                        at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt=""></a>

                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>

                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida
                        at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You need index here, if remainder of index with 4 is 0. tags should be closed and reopened.

Comment: You do it wrong - in bootstrap the thumbnail list can contain more thumbnails. If the row is full, the next thumbnail appear in a new line

Comment: Hmm, something funky is going on then, if the row gets full then the next row of thumbnails is miss-aligned.. hence why I though I had to put them on a separate row.. What would be causing it have the second row shoved over to the side?

Comment: Found the issue, in bootstrap there is a rule that affects the first child thumbnail of a row to remove the left margin, but obviously the ones that overflow onto the next line are not a first child. How could I fix that and avoid the extra markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `name` for the `foreach` loop and then check the iteration number, something like this:

```
{foreach from=$array item=var name=myloop}

    {if $smarty.foreach.myloop.iteration % 4 == 1}
        {* this is the first in a group of four *}
    {elseif $smarty.foreach.myloop.iteration % 4 == 0}
        {* this is the last in a group of four *}
    {else}
        {* this is the second or the third *}
    {/if}

{/foreach}
```

Read through the [documentation of `foreach`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach) for more details.  Specifically look at `iteration` and `index`.

Comment: Oops, yes, of course, typo and then copy/paste :)  Thanks - fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are using **Smarty v3**, you can directly use `@iteration` on the variable :

```
{foreach $array as $var}
    {if $var@iteration %4 == 1}
        <div class="row">
    {/if}
        <div class="span3"><!-- ... --></div>
    {if $var@iteration %4 == 0}
        </div><!-- /div.row -->
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

[Smarty doc](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.iteration)

---

The other thing is, the `.thumbnails` is meant to be used as a `.row` but it allows more than the classic 12 cells.

So I don't know if it handles `.row-fluid` very well. That's why your workaround needs several *hard*-rows.

The best course of action would be to define the width of the spans yourself, or wait for a `.thumbnails-fluid` implementation like this one : [Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/KpaZu/)

```css
.thumbnails.thumbnails-fluid { margin-left: 0; }
.thumbnails.thumbnails-fluid > [class*="span"] {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  margin-left: 2.127659574468085%;
  *margin-left: 2.074468085106383%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
.thumbnails.thumbnails-fluid .span12 { width: 100%; *width: 99.94680851063829%; }
.thumbnails.thumbnails-fluid .span11 { width: 91.48936170212765%; *width: 91.43617021276594%; }
.thumbnails.thumbnails-fluid .span10 { width: 82.97872340425532%; *width: 82.92553191489361%; }
.thumbnails.thumbnails-fluid .span9 { width: 74.46808510638297%; *width: 74.41489361702126%; }
.thumbnails.thumbnails-fluid .span8 { width: 65.95744680851064%; *width: 65.90425531914893%; }
.thumbnails.thumbnails-fluid .span7 { width: 57.44680851063829%; *width: 57.39361702127659%; }
.thumbnails.thumbnails-fluid .span6 { width: 48.93617021276595%; *width: 48.88297872340425%; }
.thumbnails.thumbnails-fluid .span5 { width: 40.42553191489362%; *width: 40.37234042553192%; }
.thumbnails.thumbnails-fluid .span4 { width: 31.914893617021278%; *width: 31.861702127659576%; }
.thumbnails.thumbnails-fluid .span3 { width: 23.404255319148934%; *width: 23.351063829787233%; }
.thumbnails.thumbnails-fluid .span2 { width: 14.893617021276595%; *width: 14.840425531914894%; }
.thumbnails.thumbnails-fluid .span1 { width: 6.382978723404255%; *width: 6.329787234042553%; }
```